# Prototype 1.6.0.3 - "Insert is not a function"

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm going berserk with this. Although http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/insert is far from being the best documentation page ever, I struggle with a really stupid simple implementation:

```
$('account').insert({'top':new Element('a')});
```

I also tried with a plain HTML string instead of new Element(a), but it doesn't change anything... Can you spot what's wrong with what I'm doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, the semicolon terminates a statement. You don't want to terminate the statement there, you wanted to call `.insert` on the result of `$('account')`, so don't put a semicolon there.

According to the documentation you linked, you're also missing a set of curly braces and some quotes.

```
$('account').insert({'top': new Element('a')});
```

Comment: ; was due to a bad paste...
I corrected as you say, but I still get the same error msg...

Answer (score 3):

Prototype returns `null` from `$("foo")` if no element with "id" value "foo" is on the page. If you're using the "id" value "account" on *multiple* elements, anything might happen, so don't do that. Otherwise make sure there's an element with "id" value "account" on the page when that code runs.